# macOS Mojave: Mail accounts not appearing after clean install

Tags: macos, email

I've just finished a clean install of macOS Mojave on my mid-2012 MacBook Pro, which is on the list of supported devices. I tried recovering Mail by copying the following folders/files from my TimeMachine backup and putting them in their respective locations on my new Mojave install:

- Mail content (~16GB for me): `~/Library/Mail/`
- Mail preferences: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`

I then fired up Mail, upon which it needs to "optimise my accounts" etc. (the folder in `~/Library/Mail/` called `V3` changes to `V6`), but then it opens into an empty window. None of my previous accounts are anywhere to be seen. The files in the `Mail/V6` folder are still there.

Restart of machine *after* copying *but before* opening Mail for the first time does not help. I tried removing the ACL that TimeMachine normally adds to files, using `$ chmod -R -N ~/Library/Mail/`, but this made no difference.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening? Importing the mailboxes results only in folders under "On My Mac" while the accounts I had were active IMAP accounts.